# Как запретить камере выходить за границы Tilemap?

Tags: unity3d, tilemap

Скрипт почти дописан опытным путем)), но остается один вопрос:
Как получить эти же значения формулой, что бы в будущем приближать-отдалять и ничего не сбивалось? Это значения когда камера доходит до границы TileMap cameraPos on bounds = x2.4 y2 (при orthographicSize = 5)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 mousePos;
    GameManager gameManager;
    float boundX;
    float boundY;

    private void Start()
    {
        gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
        boundX = gameManager.gameMapSize.x - 1;
        boundY = gameManager.gameMapSize.y - 1;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            mousePos.x -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") / 2;
            if (mousePos.x > 2.4f)
            {
                mousePos.x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") / 2;
            }
            mousePos.y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") / 2;
            if (mousePos.y > 2f)
            {
                mousePos.y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") / 2;
            }
            mousePos.z = transform.position.z;
            Debug.Log(mousePos.x + " " + mousePos.y);
            Camera.main.transform.position = mousePos;
        }
    }
    void ValidPos()
    {
        Camera cam = Camera.main;
        float height = 2f * cam.orthographicSize;
        float width = height * cam.aspect;
        //Height: 10
        //Width: 21.21
        //tilemapSize = x26, y14
        //cameraPos on bounds = x2.4 y2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечаю на свой вопрос - откуда цифры?
2.39f = (TilemapHeight - cameraHeight)/2
2f = (TIlemapWidth - cameraWidth)/2

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 mousePos;
    GameManager gameManager;
    float boundX;
    float boundY;
    private void Start()
    {
        gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            GetTilemapBound();
            mousePos.x -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") / 2;
            if (mousePos.x > boundX || mousePos.x < -boundX)
            {
                mousePos.x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") / 2;
            }
            mousePos.y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") / 2;
            if (mousePos.y > boundY || mousePos.y < -boundY)
            {
                mousePos.y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") / 2;
            }
            mousePos.z = transform.position.z;
            Camera.main.transform.position = mousePos;
        }
    }
    private void GetTilemapBound()
    {
        float mainCameraSize = Camera.main.orthographicSize;
        float height = 2f * mainCameraSize;
        float width = height * Camera.main.aspect;
        boundX = (gameManager.gameMapSize.x - width) / 2;
        boundY = (gameManager.gameMapSize.y - height) / 2;
    }
}
```